# Finding the distribution of $X$ conditional on the event $\{X > \psi\}$

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, conditional-probability

## **Warning**

I have divided the question into two subquestions: the first concerns the conditional distribution, which I discuss here; the second part is found in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/602904/some-questions-for-s-min-x-1-x-n-and-pareto-density-function).

## **Exercise**

Let $X \thicksim Pa(\lambda, \theta)$ with density function
$
f(x; \theta, \lambda) = \frac{\lambda \theta^{\lambda}}{x^{\lambda+1}}
$
where $x \geq \theta$, $\lambda > 0$ and $\theta > 0$.

Fixed $\psi > 0$, find the distribution of $X$ conditional on the event $\{X > \psi\}$.

## **Try**

First, I have found the CDF of $X$
$$
F_X (x)  = P(X \leq x) 
= \int^{x}_{\theta} \frac{\lambda \theta^{\lambda}}{t^{\lambda+1}} dt 
= \lambda \theta^{\lambda} \int^{x}_{\theta} \frac{1}{t^{\lambda+1}} dt 
= \lambda \theta^{\lambda} \int^{x}_{\theta} t^{-(\lambda+1)} dt  
$$

$$
F_X (x) = \lambda \theta^{\lambda} \left[ \frac{ t^{-\lambda}}{-\lambda} \right]^{x}_{\theta} 
= \lambda \theta^{\lambda}  \left[ \frac{ x^{-\lambda}}{-\lambda} - \frac{ \theta^{-\lambda}}{-\lambda} \right]
= - \theta^{\lambda}x^{-\lambda} + 1 = 1 - \left( \frac{\theta}{x} \right)^{\lambda}
$$

So far I'm in, but after that I wouldn't know how to proceed.

**UPDATE**

I have understood because when I calculate the integral of the density doesn't provide me the CDF. I didn't insert $\theta$ as lower bound in the integral. Sorry. Now I have fixed it.

Meanwhile, I have found this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2490341/finding-conditional-pdf-and-conditional-cdf) in which the calculation is given by:
$$
P(X \leq x | X > \psi) = \frac{F(x) - F(\psi)}{1 - F(\psi)} 1_{(\psi,+\infty)}(x)
$$

where $1_{(\psi,+\infty)}(x)$ is the indicator function for the set $(\psi,+\infty)$. So, let's proceed:

$$
\begin{align*}
F_{X|X>\psi}(x) & = P(X \leq x | X > \psi) = \frac{F(x) - F(\psi)}{1 - F(\psi)} 1_{(\psi,+\infty)}(x) \\
& = \frac{1 - \left( \frac{\theta}{x} \right)^{\lambda} - 1 + \left( \frac{\theta}{\psi} \right)^{\lambda}}{1 - 1 + \left( \frac{\theta}{\psi} \right)^{\lambda}} 
= \frac{\left( \frac{\theta}{\psi} \right)^{\lambda} - \left( \frac{\theta}{x} \right)^{\lambda} }{\left( \frac{\theta}{\psi} \right)^{\lambda}} \\
& = 1 - \frac{\left( \frac{\theta}{x} \right)^{\lambda} }{\left( \frac{\theta}{\psi} \right)^{\lambda}} 
= 1 - \frac{\theta^{\lambda}}{x^{\lambda}} \cdot  \frac{\psi^{\lambda}}{\theta^{\lambda}} \\
& = 1 - \left( \frac{\psi}{x} \right)^{\lambda}
\end{align*}
$$

Finally, I have the CDF: $F_{X|X>\psi}(x)= 1 - \left( \frac{\psi}{x} \right)^{\lambda}1_{(\psi,+\infty)}(x)$.

Comment: Your calculation of the cdf, $F_X(x)$ is wrong; there's at least two errors on the right hand side of the first equation. I didn't look beyond that.

Comment: @Glen_b Thank you for your report. I'll fix the issue.

Comment: @Glen_b I have seen the equation set for point 1 of the conditional distribution and I don't notice any errors in the CDF calculation. Could you point me to what you are referring to?

Comment: Your very first formula for the CDF is wrong (the right hand side doesn't even depend on $x$!) and the result you get is nonsensical: no CDF can be constant, nor can it have negative values (its values are probabilities, after all).

Comment: @whuber because $F_X(x) = P(X \leq x) = \int^{x}_{-\infty} f(t)dt$. Right? If I was true, maybe, I really made some mistakes.

Comment: @whuber I have calculated just now the CDF and the result is $F_X(x) = - (\theta/x)^{\lambda}$. This was the CDF I was supposed to be looking for, right?

Comment: @whuber Besides I have done the control with the derivative and it provides me the density function. OMG I made some wrongs... Thank you very much for your report, I was doing crazy calculations without consciousness.

Comment: Again: any function that returns a negative value for even one argument cannot possibly be a CDF.  You're close, so consider checking your result by differentiating it and comparing to the original density.  Also consider the limiting value of $F(x)$ as $x$ grows large: the axiom of total probability implies this limit must be $1.$  Plotting your solution is *always* a good idea because you can easily see whether it has these two fundamental properties (plus the others that make it a CDF, like left continuity).

Comment: @whuber I have studied $F(x)$ when $x$ grows large and I find that the limit is $0^{-}$.  $F(-x)$ has as limit $0^{+}$. $F(x)$ has right continuity. The integral of density on $\mathbb{R}$ is 1. I have plotted the function and it seems an hyperbolic function. The behaviuor of $F(x)$ seems ok according to plot. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: $F$ must increase to an upper limit of $1,$ not $0,$ as $x$ grows large.  In your calculations you overlooked the fact that $f$ is *zero* for all $x\lt \theta.$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142260/discussion-between-istats7238-and-whuber).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
f(x; \theta, \lambda) = \frac{\lambda \theta^{\lambda}}{x^{\lambda+1}}
$
So,
$$
F(x) = \int_\theta^x f(t)\,dt = \lambda \theta^\lambda \left[\frac{-1}{\lambda}t^{-\lambda}\right]_\theta^x = \theta^\lambda (\theta^{-\lambda} - x^{-\lambda}) = 1 - (\tfrac{\theta}{x})^\lambda
$$
and
$$
P(X \leq x \mid X > \psi) = 
\frac{P(X \leq x \cap X > \psi)}{P(X > \psi)} = \frac{F(x) - F(\psi)}{1 - F(\psi)} = \frac{(\tfrac{\theta}{\psi})^\lambda - (\tfrac{\theta}{x})^\lambda}{(\tfrac{\theta}{\psi})^\lambda}= 1 -(\tfrac{\psi}{x})^\lambda.$$